# Why do I get a KeyError when I try to access the first item of this JSON file in a python script

Tags: python, json, dictionary, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to loop through a JSON config file, and process each service one at a time. I want to grab the the service_name in this code, but it gives me a KeyError: 0.

I've tried looping through it in various ways, but each method I tried gave me the key error.

```
{
  "my_services": [
    {
      "service_name" : "Exchange Online",
      "region": [
        "NorthCentral",
        "SouthCentral"
      ],
      "firewall": [
        "ABC",
        "DEF"
      ],
      "firewall_ip" : "12.23.34.455",
      "firewall_type" : "cde",
      "endpointURL" : "something.com",
      "parserType" : "parseO365Delta.py"
    },
    {
      "service_name" : "Microsoft 365 Common and Office Online",
      "region": [
        "NorthCentral",
        "SouthCentral"
      ],
      "firewall": [
        "ABC"
      ],
      "firewall_ip" : "98.87.76.655",
      "firewall_type" : "abc",
      "endpointURL" : "alsosomething.com",
      "parserType" : "parseO365Delta.py"
    }
  ]
}
```

```py
import json
import subprocess

def processService(service):
    for item in service[0].values():
        print(item)

def main():
    with open('config.json', 'r') as config:
        config_list = json.load(config)

    for services in config_list["my_services"]:
        processService(services) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `"my_services"` is a list of dicts.

`service` inside `processService` is a dictionary, not a list. Hence

```
for item in service[0].values():
```

should be changed to

```
for item in service.values():
```

Comment: Right, but that would return every item in the list, whereas I wanted only the first one which was "service_names". I was able to find a solution, that I posted below. Thank you for taking the time to help me too.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I was able to figure it out by using the dictionary method get, which given a key in the dictionary, returns the associated value.

The line of code I used to get the associated value is:

```
def processService(service):
    print(service.get("service_name"))
```

This returns every associated service_name in my config list.